# Pattern в input элементе

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения, html5, сопоставление-с-образцом

мне нужно паттерн чтобы пользователь мог вывести только (1-100) потом + потом (1 или к или кк) )

```
<input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="????" >
```

Comment: я получил ответ от Arendach. Как оказалось что ему понятно а им нет???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте это:

```
^([1-9][0-9]?|100)(\+)(1|к|кк)$
```

Вот пример: https://regex101.com/r/kIOK3C/1